# Port 111 shows up open when I nmap 127.0.0.1

Tags: linux, networking, port

I can see port 111 open (nmap output: 111/tcp open  rpcbind ) and rpcbind is running on it (I'm using GNU-Linux system). What is rpcbind and why is it running? I did not start it (or at least I don't know about it), also I was reading about it and 
`sudo netstat -ap | grep 111`
should show the process using the port but it outputs nothing.

Is this normal (I don't think because the port is open whenever I boot the machine)? How to identify what's going on?

Can this mean that I am hacked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 111`

it is usually used by `portmapper` and often installed by default (it is required for NFS mounts and such). So (most probably) nothing to worry about.

You can remove that package if you don't use it, and it will go away.

Comment: Output is 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      330/rpcbind         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      330/rpcbind         
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           330/rpcbind         
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                330/rpcbind 
what's up with that?

Comment: `dpkg --list | grep portmapper` does not show portmapper is installed:(

Comment: @Tarotor When you need to post the output for some commands, edit your question and post the output there. In question, it gets more attention.

Comment: @Tarotor it might be called `rpcbind` or such. Try `dpkg -S /usr/sbin/rpcbind` (or wherever the deamon is) to find what package it is in, and then use `apt-get remove` to remove it and all dependant packages (after verifying you're ok with that, of course!)